# How can I connect the module described in the lib directory?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I has a problem with my [website](https://menacetopests.com/).
I want to extend the functionality of the controller using additional methods that I described in the module "module MyLib" (lib directory).  In the controller, I write "include Example", but the methods described in the module do not work in the controller.  Error: "NameError: uninitialized constant MyLib".  How can I connect the module described in the lib directory?

Answer (score 1):

Files in your `lib` folder aren't automatically loaded in the application if it's not explicitly done within the environment configuration.

A simple workaround would be to use require referring to the complete path the file has;

The module;

```
# lib/foo/bar.rb
module Foo
  module Bar
    def hola
      :hola
    end
  end
end
```

The controller;

```
# app/controllers/home_controller.rb
require Rails.root.join('lib/foo/bar')

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  include ::Foo::Bar

  def root
    render json: hola
  end
end
```

The route;

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#root'
end
```

Doing `app.get('/')` should return `"\"hola\""`;

```
# in the rails console
app.get('/')
# Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-12-20 17:23:03 +0100
# Processing by HomeController#root as HTML
# Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 124)
=> 200
app.body
=> "\"hola\""
```